# how to calculate age from date of brith and store it in the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I want to calculate age in years from date of birth and store it in my age column in my database
below is what i have done so far. i have added images of the database and my date of birth on my page.I want to calculate on store it into the database without displaying the age on my page.Thanks in advance

```
 <div class="form-group">
     label for="date_of_birth">Date of birth</label>

 <div class="input-group date form_date col-md-5" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($date_of_birth)) echo $date_of_birth; ?>" size="16" readonly>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
             </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" name="date_of_birth" value="<?php if(isset($date_of_birth)) echo $date_of_birth; ?>" /><br/>
            </div></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        //language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        showMeridian: 1
    });
    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0
    });
    $('.form_time').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 1,
        minView: 0,
        maxView: 1,
        forceParse: 0
    });
</script>
```

[image for my date of birth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HTFc.png)

[image for my database fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOyQl.png)

Comment: Storing the age in the database is not a good idea.  Each time you want to get the age, just use the DOB and work it out (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788542/how-to-store-birthdate-and-age-so-that-age-can-be-updated-daily-in-php-mysql)

Comment: @Nigel Ren. i have this search engine with age as one of the filters. this is the reason i wanted to store age

Comment: As I've already stated, you have the DOB so work out the age when you do the search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate age from jquery datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137763/how-to-calculate-age-from-jquery-datepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add or subtract dates with JavaScript - if they are formatted as dates:

```js
const birthDate = new Date('1980.02.18')
const today = new Date(Date.now())

console.log('birth date:', birthDate)
console.log('today:', today)

console.log('age in years:', new Date(birthDate - today).getYear())
```

This is a simple process, so as @NigeRen wrote: "Storing the age in the database is not good idea."